# How can i fix internal server error?HTTP ERROR:500

Tags: spring, gradle, kotlin

I`m trying to study kotlin servelet.
Then when I run my project my server does not work well.
This project is created from google-app-engine and use google-cloud-datastore.
How to fix it?

My server displays it.

[image: Errors]

This is my build.gradle.kts file.

```
plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.3.10"
    war
    kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("kapt") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("plugin.noarg") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.asciidoctor.convert") version "1.5.3"
    id("com.adarshr.test-logger") version "1.3.1"
    confidential
    flystore
    jacoco
}
apply {
    plugin("com.google.cloud.tools.appengine-standard")
}
```

How can I fix it. please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason is that I have no any permission for google appengine.
So I changed public key on the environment file shell/env.proto.sh.
Setted key is following...

export JWT_PRIVATE_KEY=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
export JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvsyx5ZnoPq6X6ELgghxuqYcdL7j/m33D07w89tqr8toUaNZUJrNDUlVP7HxS+wpMELiuNEeCGKnsruCt+xMzGtYhjPHJQG1RtDXvw77knann5F10YLEt7BG8SrZxJq9hJ0vMkBATu2W4awBiLh/aYiUKgg00P+Dn2AAnKVPAseBoikBur0nThkySw8hw8qG34P5e8Bp8HUfzY8PywJhwsl6aEIO7TIkTgyRi0udBgjiJ4ty8ww/zVrEur3L24GQyHKRMgeXksrc1UuEYIULKeM6ZMZ6cUN5OXRH+GN1rnk9Ayc8Uh6jQVNUbysSlNaS18vsG9NOD/LHolAkAezO2vwIDAQAB

This is very important to use google app-engine.

Comment: I hope this is not actually your private key. If so, I hope you changed it long ago. Private keys are supposed to be *private*; publishing one is a huge security error.